# I need to install .Net 2.0 on 50+ computers, what is the fastest/easiest way to do that?

Tags: windows, networking, .net

I wrote a little .Net 2.0 application that my users wanted. However I need to update all of their computers to .Net 2.0 (I had considered going all the way to 3.5 but the install time is brutal)

What is the fastest and easiest way to install .Net 2.0 on all my user's machines?

Thanks,

-Biff

Comment: sorry I can't help myself, getting 50+ people to do it. ;>0

Comment: haha, they don't have admin access to their pcs :P

Comment: May be of help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480242.aspx check out the section Distributing Dotnetfx.exe Using an Electronic Software Distribution Tool

Comment: Have you considered a WSUS server?

Answer (score 4):

Within a domain you can package it up as an msi and use group policy to deploy to their PCs.

Comment: I'm not sure what any of that means.

Comment: An .msi is a windows installer package, and group policy is the way you can force settings onto objects in ActiveDirectory.

Answer (score 1):

If you have that many PCs you should really be using WSUS for patch management, in which case that's by far the simplest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There are various methods described in the [**.NET Framework 2.0 Deployment Guide**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480237.aspx)
including SMS and as Alex mentioned) Push it out via Active Directory / msi.

I would also recommend that you have a look at the .NET 3.5 Deployment guide ([**for developers**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc160716.aspx) | [**for administrators**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc160717.aspx)) as it has some updated information related to newer versions of things like Active Directory.